# Why does my table with fixed width and centered content not work?

Tags: tables

My goal is to create a table, that has columns which are fixed in width and which contain centered content.

This is my table which works fine:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | }
    \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
    Inhalt & Inhalt & Inhalt \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Fixed width for all three columns works also fine:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | m{1cm} | m{1cm} | m{1cm} | }
```

Fixed width and centered applied to only two columns works fine as well:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | >{\centering} m{1cm} | >{\centering} m{1cm} | c | }
```

Fixed width and centered applied to all three columns makes Texmaker print out an multiple errors:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | >{\centering} m{1cm} | >{\centering} m{1cm} | >{\centering} m{1cm} | }
```

Errors are:

For line 3

```
! Misplaced \noalign.\hline ->\noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \let \hskip \vskip \let \vrule \hrule \let... col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
```

For line 3

```
! Misplaced \noalign.\hline ->\noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \let \hskip \vskip \let \vrule \hrule \let... col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
```

For line 4

```
! Misplaced \noalign.\hline ->\noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \let \hskip \vskip \let \vrule \hrule \let... col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `\centering\arraybackslash`

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabularray` and don't worry anymore about `\centering\arraybackslash`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={*3{Q[c,m,1cm]}},
    hlines, vlines
    }
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\ 
    Inhalt & Inhalt & Inhalt \\ 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has the same syntax as the classical `{tabular}` but had extra features. In particular, the `m`, `p` and `b` columns types have an optional argument between square brackets. With the key `c`, you will have a horizontal centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ | m[c]{1cm} | m[c]{1cm} | m[c]{1cm} | }
    \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
    Inhalt & Inhalt & Inhalt \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]